# Keep Leading Zeros in Converted CSV Using Tabular-Py and Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, tabula-py

Is there a way to maintain leading zeros in cells while still using the tabula-py convert_into function? Perhaps by passing something into the 'options' parameter to read them as strings? The documentation didn't seem very clear on what could be used there, but maybe I missed something ([Source docs](https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html))

```
# Convert PDF file to csv doc
convert_into(source_path, csv_path, output_format="csv", pages='1-2', stream=True)
```

Comment: if you can't find something in `source doc` then maybe search in `source code`

Comment: Source code only has this: "options (str, optional):
            Raw option string for tabula-java." which matches the source docs. https://github.com/chezou/tabula-py/blob/cefa1f40d602da4cc97882ad9f156418e270e565/tabula/io.py#L686

Answer (score 0):

If I open the csv in something other than Excel, and actually see the leading zeros still there. The solution that seems to work is to update the pandas.read_csv() function by passing dtype=str like so:

```
# Convert csv to Excel doc
csv = pd.read_csv(csv_path, dtype=str)
csv.to_excel(excel_path, index=False, header=True)
```